# Sql Query that somehow converts months to 4 seasons

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query in sql server that let's me get get month registered in my table and somehow covert those months into 4 seasons(autumn,fall,spring,summer). Does anyone know how to make this done??

Comment: Show your code and efforts!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One method is a `case`.  Your question doesn't clarify the logic, but here is an example:

```
(case when month(date) in (12, 1, 2) then 'winter'
      when month(date) in (3, 4, 5) then 'spring'
      when month(date) in (6, 7, 8) then 'summer'
      when month(date) in (9, 10, 11) then 'autumn'
 end) as season
```

Comment: Hopefully, his application won't be run accross multiple locations, or his season-splitting conditionals would take miles.

Comment: Important to note that this only works in one hemisphere (specifically northern). You'd need to add some switch to account for different hemispheres if you need to support that.

Answer (score 2):

```
(CHOOSE(month(TheDate),'Winter', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Spring', 'Spring', 
 'Summer', 'Summer', 'Summer', 'Autumn', 'Autumn', 'Autumn', 'Winter'))
```

Comment: In case anyone is going "what?" This is defining the season name for the month number which the month(TheDate) returns. :)

Answer (score -1):

changed linoff's answer to:

```
case dateatepart(quarter,idate)  
      when 1 then 'winter'
      when 2 then 'spring'
      when 3  then 'summer'
      when 4 then 'autumn'
 end as season
```

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your answer completely

Comment: changed linoff's answer to:
case dateatepart(quarter,idate)  
     when 2 then winter'
      when 2 then 'spring'
      when 3  then 'summer'
      when 4 then 'autumn'
 end as season

Comment: This doesn't work for seasons, as they don't map to the months of the year like that. (Winter/Summer depending on hemisphere is months 1,2,12).